# Glom assign using a Check filter

Tags: python, glom

I'm trying to use the `glom.assign` operator to [deeply assign](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mutation.html) and only set on one of the children in a list.  As a complication, the correct child to set depends on a property of that child.  Can I use `assign` and `Check` to assign *some* children's values, based on properties of the contained elements?

As as simple example, trying to get the float value from the list works.  But using the same spec with `assign` fails (stack trace hidden for clarity):

```
>>> from glom import glom, Check, SKIP, assign
>>> test = {"root": [{"name": "child1", "type": "bool", "value": True},
                     {"name": "child2", "type": "int", "value": 1,},
                     {"name": "child3", "type": "float", "value": 1.0}]}
>>> spec = ("root", [Check("type", equal_to="float", default=SKIP)], "0", "value")
>>> glom(test, spec)
1.0

>>> assign(test, spec, 2.0)
...
TypeError: path argument must be a .-delimited string, Path, T, or S
```

How should I do property-based filtering when using glom's assign?

(I have glom-20.11.0 installed.)